# Emacs - Adding abbrevs in ess-mode

Tags: emacs, ess

I can't seem to get abbrevs working in ess-mode when editing R files.

I have ess-mode hook to activate abbrev-mode, but I get no expansion for my global abbrevs. When I do `add-mode-abbrev` I can add an abbrev, but it is not written to my abbrev file and of course doesn't get ever expanded (after `read-abbrev-file` or restart).

If I by hand add something like this into my abbrev file and reload:

```
(define-abbrev-table 'ess-mode-abbrev-table
'(
    ("-=" "<-" nil 0)
))
```

it doesn't work either.

How can I make ess-mode aware of my abbrevs?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a workaround setting the ess-mode-abbrev-table locally. First I define the abbrev-table, just in case that I load my abbrev-tables later and don't want an error when starting ESS:

```
(define-abbrev-table 'ess-mode-abbrev-table nil)
(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq local-abbrev-table ess-mode-abbrev-table)))
```

I prefer to use the same abbrevs in the interpreter, so this comes in handy:

```
(dolist (hook '(ess-mode-hook inferior-ess-mode-hook))
  (add-hook hook
        (lambda ()
          (setq local-abbrev-table ess-mode-abbrev-table))))
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Little more explanation.

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising: `list-abbrevs` now shows (ess-mode-abbrev-table) "-="           0    "<-", but it still doen't expand the abbreviation. `local-abbrev-table` is [## 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -= 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] (so it too contains the trigger...). Do you do any further setting please?

Comment: The docstring of `define-abbrev-table` sheds light on your issue: "If :regexp is nil, the default behavior uses backward-word and forward-word to extract the name of the abbrev, which can therefore only be a single word." So changing the name of your abbreviation to "u" for underscore for example should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Abbreviations are expected to have word-syntax - `forward-word` is used internally.

Writing/re-defining abbrevs is a costly operation, takes some seconds. Thus this is not done after any edit/definition - except when <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd> is asked for explicitly. Abbrev-file commonly is written when session is closed.

Comment: That is correct, but not my issue - I call read-abbrev-file and it still doesn't work. Abbrevs work correctly in other modes. There is a disconnect between ess-mode and abbrev-mode and that is what I need to get fixed...